Docker-Compose MySQL and WordPress Environment Variable Issue
I'm setting up a local development environment for a WordPress project using Docker Compose, including WordPress, MySQL, and Adminer containers. Here’s my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.8'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:6
    container_name: wp_dev
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${MYSQL_HOST}
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "8008:80"
    volumes:
      - ./wp-data:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5
    container_name: mysql_dev
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3305:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data_dev:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    container_name: adminer_dev
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  db_data_dev:


And my corresponding .env file:
MYSQL_HOST=db:3305
MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_USER=user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_pw

However, I'm encountering a connection error between WordPress and MySQL (see screenshot).

Interestingly, when I modify all the environment variables to use the value "wordpress" and remove any port from the MYSQL_HOST variable, the connection works perfectly. Here’s the modified .env:
MYSQL_HOST=db
MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=wordpress
MYSQL_USER=wordpress
MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress

Can anyone explain why the connection fails when I use different environment variable values and specify a port? Is there something wrong with my setup or configuration?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Update:
Thanks to @Dean Ayalon I have understood the problem with the port.
Now my .env file looks like this:
MYSQL_HOST=db # alternativ db:3306
MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_USER=user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_pw

I am still getting the error from the screenshot in this case.

Because the container uses port 3306, not 3305
Port 3305 is only the host machine's port that is mapped to the container port 3306. Still to access the container's service, you need to reach container port 3306, that's where it listens
If nothing is accessing your db externally, and it's only used by other container services, you don't need to map those ports at all

Thanks for the quick reply! This explains and solves the port problem.
However, I still have the problem with the other environment variables. Can you explain that? Other tutorials that can be found online use exactly the same variables and of course different values (e.g. https://www.codeconcisely.com/posts/docker-wordpress/)

The reason is because you're specifying a port number, when you use db:3305 it tries connecting to port 3305, which is the wrong one. When you use just db, it connect to port 3306, the default port for MySQL. You can use db:3306, it'd be the same. Or am I getting your question wrong?

Even if I change the value MYSQL_HOST to db or db:3306, I still get the error “Error establishing a database connection”. If I change all other values to “wordpress”, everything works fine. (I edited the question accordingly)

I have the feeling there is some kind of caching problem with the variables from the .env.
I have copied the docker-compose file to another folder with the following .env:
MYSQL_HOST=db:3306
MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_USER=user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_pwd
-->
I was then able to successfully start WordPress in this folder.
If I then run “docker-compose down” and adjust a variable (e.g. MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_pass), the error occurs again when running “docker-compose up”.
